# Left join mysql query in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table which contain this values

```
 id   username   attribute             op  value 
  1     asd       Cleartext-password    :=   text
  2     asd       expiration            :=   02 DEC 2017 2:5:30
  3     asd       ftg-quota             :=    500
```

we can note that username column has same value but the others columns have different 
I want to select all user's information if his account expired (I can know if his account expired if attribute =expiration and value

```
SELECT
  e.username,
  e.attribute,
  e.value AS expired,
  c.attribute,
  c.value AS password,
  c.telefon AS phone,
  c.adsoyad AS realname,
  c.email AS email
FROM radcheck e
LEFT JOIN radcheck c
  ON c.attribute = 'Cleartext-Password'
  AND e.attribute = 'Expiration'
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(e.value, '%d %M %Y %h:%i'), '%d %M %Y %h:%i') <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d %M %Y %h:%i')
AND e.username = c.username
GROUP BY e.username
```

this is another query which I used without result

```
SELECT
  c.username,
  MAX(CASE
    WHEN c.attribute = 'Cleartext-Password' THEN c.value
  END) AS password,
  MAX(CASE
    WHEN c.attribute = 'Expiration' THEN c.value
  END) AS expiration,
  MAX(CASE
    WHEN c.attribute = 'Ftg-Total-Limit' THEN c.value
  END) AS quta,
  MAX(CASE
    WHEN c.attribute = 'Simultaneous-Use' THEN c.value
  END) AS simul,
  MAX(CASE
    WHEN c.attribute = 'Max-All-Session' THEN c.value
  END) AS session,
  MAX(c.adsoyad) AS realname,
  MIN(c.dtarih) AS birthdate,
  MIN(c.telefon) AS phone,
  MIN(c.tcno) AS tc,
  MAX(c.email) AS email,
  MIN(c.id) AS id
FROM radcheck c
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(expiration, '%d %M %Y %h:%i'), '%d %M %Y %h:%i') <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d %M %Y %h:%i')
GROUP BY c.username
```

Comment: Your table structure and your query are inconsistent.

Comment: no It consistent

Comment: Can you replace `AND e.attribute = 'Expiration'` with `AND e.attribute = 'expiration'` data in tables is case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  e.username,
  e.attribute,
  e.value AS password,
  e.telefon AS phone,
  e.adsoyad AS realname,
  e.email AS email
FROM radcheck e
     LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT distinct username
       FROM radcheck e 
       WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(e.value, '%d %M %Y %h:%i'), '%d %M %Y %h:%i') <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d %M %Y %h:%i')
      ) c
ON c.username=e.username
```

You can join to the subquery. The subquery returns list of usernames which are expired.

Comment: "Not working" means nothing. What exactly not working? Any errors? Does the subquery works?

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'c.attribute' in 'field list' and I tried to solve it without result

Comment: Updated - actually e.attribute should be used. `c` does not have all the columns except username

Answer (score 0):

`expiration` in your second query is an aggregation result. It doesn't exist before aggregation and can hence not be used in `WHERE`. Use `HAVING` instead.

Then you want to compare datetimes, but you compare strings instead. But the string `'02 JAN 1900 12:34'` is greater than `'01 DEC 2017 12:34'` for instance, because string comparision has no built-in date detection, but compares character by charater (`'02...' > '01...'`).

The corrected query:

```
SELECT
  username,
  MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'Cleartext-Password' THEN value END) AS password,
  MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'Expiration'         THEN value END) AS expiration,
  MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'Ftg-Total-Limit'    THEN value END) AS quta,
  MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'Simultaneous-Use'   THEN value END) AS simul,
  MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'Max-All-Session'    THEN value END) AS session,
  MAX(adsoyad) AS realname,
  MIN(dtarih) AS birthdate,
  MIN(telefon) AS phone,
  MIN(tcno) AS tc,
  MAX(email) AS email,
  MIN(id) AS id
FROM radcheck
GROUP BY username
HAVING STR_TO_DATE(MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'Expiration' THEN value END), '%d %M %Y %h:%i') <= NOW();
```